# Gradle 'apply from:' throwing exception

Tags: java, gradle, build

I am using 'apply from:' in my build.gradle script. The usage of apply from occurs in my custom plugin. Have anyone else faced problem like this before?

```
apply from: '../directory/' + chosenSubDir + '/build.gradle'
```

I receive following exception:

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.gradle.api.Project
```

My point is to get all sections from proper file (also build.gradle) and assign them to a fields of a helper class which will store this data.

EDIT:
For now, whole code is in build.main script but eventually it will splitted.

```
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    project.extensions.create('myFile', HelperClass)

    project.task('task') {
        doLast {
           //listing files

           //choosing file by user

           //here receiving an exception \/
           apply from: '../DirWithFiles/' + chosenFile

           //further operations with content of chosen file
        }
    }
}

class HelperClass {
    def config = {
        set {}
        map {}
        //etc..
    }
}

apply plugin: MyPlugin
```

I invoke my plugin by calling ./gradlew task

Comment: It should work, please share the whole build.gradle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Opal Please take a look on the code I shared.

Comment: Why do you `apply` in a task? `apply` should be called at the very beginning of the plugin.

Comment: @Opal But in this task I need to choose file, and after file is chosen I need to apply it to my project.myFile object. I can't image how would I achieve this having apply on the beginning of my plugin.

Comment: Ok, so instead of just `apply` try `project.apply`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Opal advised me to do, I used 'project.apply from' instead of 'apply from' and it works fine now. Thank you!